# Unable to deploy flask application using wheel file on local machine

Tags: python, flask, python-wheel

Created a flask application by following tutorial on the [flask documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/tutorial/). Project Directory structure in VS Code

```
/home/user/Projects/flask-tutorial
├── flaskr/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── db.py
│   ├── schema.sql
│   ├── auth.py
│   ├── blog.py
│   ├── templates/
│   │   ├── base.html
│   │   ├── auth/
│   │   │   ├── login.html
│   │   │   └── register.html
│   │   └── blog/
│   │       ├── create.html
│   │       ├── index.html
│   │       └── update.html
│   └── static/
│       └── style.css
├── tests/
├── .venv/
├── pyproject.toml
└── MANIFEST.in
```

I am able to run the flask web app in VS Code terminal in my project directory but I am unable to run it elsewhere in local machine even after installing the wheel file.

```
python -m build --wheel
```

Output: flaskr-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl file

I then copied the wheel file to a different directory on my local machine, created a new virtual environment and pip installed the wheel file.

Trying to run the flaskr application using the terminal is giving me an import error (below). Am I missing something?

```
cp flaskr-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl ~/Documents 
cd ~/Documents 
xxx@vincent Documents % source .venv/bin/activate
(.venv) xxx@vincent Documents % pip install flaskr-1.0.0-py3-none-any.whl 
(.venv) xxx@vincent Documents % flask --app flaskr run

Usage: flask run [OPTIONS]
Try 'flask run --help' for help.

Error: Could not import 'flaskr'.

(.venv) xxx@vincent Documents % pip list

Package      Version
------------ -------
blinker      1.6.2
click        8.1.3
Flask        2.3.2
flaskr       1.0.0
itsdangerous 2.1.2
Jinja2       3.1.2
MarkupSafe   2.1.3
pip          23.0.1
setuptools   67.6.1
waitress     2.1.2
```

Is there an issue with the wheel installation, I think the flaskr package is missing files:

```
(env) ****@vincent site-packages % ls -ltr
total 8
-rw-r--r--@  1 ****  staff   151 Jun 20 18:03 distutils-precedence.pth
drwxr-xr-x@  5 ****  staff   160 Jun 20 18:03 _distutils_hack
drwxr-xr-x@  6 ****  staff   192 Jun 20 18:03 pkg_resources
drwxr-xr-x@ 49 ****  staff  1568 Jun 20 18:03 setuptools
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 ****  staff   320 Jun 20 18:03 setuptools-67.6.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  9 ****  staff   288 Jun 20 18:03 pip
drwxr-xr-x@ 10 ****  staff   320 Jun 20 18:03 pip-23.0.1.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  9 ****  staff   288 Jun 20 18:03 markupsafe
drwxr-xr-x@  8 ****  staff   256 Jun 20 18:03 MarkupSafe-2.1.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 12 ****  staff   384 Jun 20 18:03 itsdangerous
drwxr-xr-x@  8 ****  staff   256 Jun 20 18:03 itsdangerous-2.1.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 20 ****  staff   640 Jun 20 18:03 click
drwxr-xr-x@  8 ****  staff   256 Jun 20 18:03 click-8.1.3.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@  8 ****  staff   256 Jun 20 18:03 blinker
drwxr-xr-x@  8 ****  staff   256 Jun 20 18:03 blinker-1.6.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 25 ****  staff   800 Jun 20 18:03 werkzeug
drwxr-xr-x@  8 ****  staff   256 Jun 20 18:03 Werkzeug-2.3.6.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 29 ****  staff   928 Jun 20 18:03 jinja2
drwxr-xr-x@  9 ****  staff   288 Jun 20 18:03 Jinja2-3.1.2.dist-info
drwxr-xr-x@ 24 ****  staff   768 Jun 20 18:03 flask
drwxr-xr-x@  9 ****  staff   288 Jun 20 18:03 Flask-2.3.2.dist-info
-rw-r--r--@  1 ****  staff     0 Jun 20 18:36 easy-install.pth

drwxr-xr-x@  9 ****  staff   288 Jun 20 18:36 flaskr-1.0.0.dist-info
```